# Cannot install packages in the Knitr environment Overleaf

Tags: knitr, overleaf

I am trying to write my R code directly in my Overleaf document using knitR. However, this message pops up when I run the following code:

<>=

```
# Install relevant packages
install.packages('wooldridge')
# Load the hprice dataset from the Wooldridge package
data(hprice1, package = 'wooldridge')
#Attach the dataset
attach(hprice1)
#Estimate a linear model
estmodel <- lm(price~assess+sqrft+lotsize+bdrms)
#Summarize the regression results
summary(estmodel)
```

[image: 1@[1]]

Comment: We are not overleaf support, please contact overleaf support. Their R setup might be a little different from normal as I believe a normal R setup would attempt to install into the users dir not system dir where you do not have write access.

Comment: This is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034656/r-knitr-sharelatex-install-packagesxyz, that have one answer, but it seems that maybe do not work ...

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] This is indeed not possible on Overleaf, sorry!

Comment: @LianTzeLim is there a way that i can import the "wooldridge" package (perhaps call it using some command) and use it in my document without installing the package itself?

Comment: I have the same problem. Does anyone find a solution ?

Comment: Is there any path you can find that _is_ user writable, and then install.packages into that? One potential way _might_ be to use `\RequirePackage{snapshot}`
 before `\documentclass{article}` and then look at the resulting `.dep` file if there are included graphics? This would give you a string that you could then `install.packages()` into.